# NaN p-value when using R's goodfit on binomial data

Tags: binomial-distribution, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I am attempting to test the goodness of fit for a vector of count data to a binomial.  To do so I am using the `goodfit()` function in the `vcd` package.  When I run the function, however, it returns `NaN` for the p-value of the Chi-squared test.  In my setup, I have a vector of count data with 75 elements.

```
> library(vcd)
> counts <- c(32, 35, 44, 35, 41, 33, 42, 49, 36, 41, 42, 45, 38, 43, 36, 
35, 40, 40, 43, 34, 39, 31, 40, 39, 36, 37, 37, 37, 32, 48, 41, 
32, 37, 36, 49, 37, 41, 36, 34, 37, 41, 32, 36, 36, 30, 33, 33, 
42, 39, 36, 36, 29, 31, 41, 36, 39, 40, 37, 39, 39, 31, 39, 37, 
40, 33, 41, 34, 46, 35, 41, 44, 38, 44, 34, 42)
> test.gof <- goodfit(counts, type="binomial", 
+                     par=list(size=length(counts), prob=0.5))
```

Everything works fine, but when I inspect the `goodfit()` object I get the following:

```
> summary(test.gof)

 Goodness-of-fit test for binomial distribution

                      X^2 df  P(> X^2)
Pearson               NaN 75       NaN
Likelihood Ratio 21.48322 19 0.3107244
Warning message:
In summary.goodfit(test.gof) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

I suspected it was a small sample size issue at first, but I also have a data set with 50 observations that does not return `NaN` for the p-value.  I have also tried to switch the method in `goodfit()` to ML with similar results.

Why would this function be producing `NaN` in this case?  Is there an alternative function to calculate GOF on count data?

Comment: @Gavin: should it be closed or could it be moved?

Comment: @Joshua If it can be moved by a mod, moved would be best as @DrewConway has done a reasonable job with the Q and reproducibility. How do we achieve a migrate? Flag the post?

Comment: Damn, I was writing an answer and had to move for 10 mins from machine. And now I came back and saw your comments. =)

Comment: This question has been merged with its near-duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

You have zero frequencies in observed counts. That explains `NaN`s in your data. If you look at `test.gof` object, you'll see that:

```
table(test.gof$observed)

 0  1  2  3  4  5  7  8 10 
56  5  3  2  5  1  1  2  1
```

you have 56 zeros. Anyway, IMHO this question is for http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the re-post from SO, but how do you recommend I deal with the zeroes given that I still want to estimate a GOF?

Comment: Hi Drew, sorry for my late answer. Well, in case of zero frequencies, it is advised (at least I was taught so) to either merge categories, since Chi-square allows some 0 frequencies (less than 20% frequencies can be 0 when the factor has more than 2 levels), if that's reasonable, or to drop Chi-square and choose an alternative technique. As I usually drop the thing, so you may want to ask another question regarding appropriate goodness-of-fit test.

Answer (score 3):

Would you be happier with a surgically altered goodfit object?

```
> idx <- which(test.gof$observed != 0)
> idx
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 49 50
> test.gof$par$size <- length(  idx-1)
> test.gof$fitted <- test.gof$fitted[idx]
> test.gof$count <- test.gof$count[idx]
> test.gof$observed <- test.gof$observed[idx]
> summary(test.gof)

     Goodness-of-fit test for binomial distribution

                      X^2 df  P(> X^2)
Pearson               Inf 75 0.0000000
Likelihood Ratio 21.48322 19 0.3107244
Warning message:
In summary.goodfit(test.gof) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: Cheater! /10char :)

Answer (score 0):

Try plotting it. You'll get a better idea of what's going on. As mentioned before, you're getting NaN because you're passing 0 frequencies to chisq.test()

```
test.gof <- goodfit(counts, type="binomial", par=list(size=length(counts), prob=0.5)) 
plot(test.gof)
## doesn't look so good 
test.gof <- goodfit(counts, type="binomial", par=list(size=length(counts))) 
plot(test.gof)
## looks a little more clear
```