# Getting NaN value for X-Squared and N/A for p-value in Chi-Square Test

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I have to perform a chi-square test on this given data set:

[image: http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2600/dataset.jpg]

Upon doing so with the following code:
[image: http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/4837/chisqcode.jpg]

I get the following result:

```
        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  data.table 
X-squared = NaN, df = 44, p-value = NA

Warning message:
In chisq.test(data.table) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Why is the X-squared value "NaN" and the p-value "N/A"? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you tell us what units of measurement your numbers are in?

Comment: Are the units of measurement even relevant? The data that I am performing the Chi-Square test upon, is composed of the monthly rainfall average(in cms) of a particular location, for 5 years:2008,2009,2010,2011,2012.

Comment: They are as relevant as anything else, because--among other things--the chi-squared test is applied to *counts.* So let's go back to the beginning, since obviously the chi-squared test is wrong here: what are you trying to learn about these data?

Comment: The numbers are monthly rainfall averages collected over a period of 5 years from a particular location. They're measured in centimetre. This is part of a school assignment in which I have to perform a chis-square test on the given data.

Comment: So, will you tell me why my X^2 is NaN and the p-value is N/A?

Comment: If you type ?chisq.test you will see that, if (as in your case) x is a vector then the values in it must be non negative integers

Comment: It simply makes no sense whatever to apply a chi-square test to these measurements. The technical reason for getting NAs is because for the months March, July and December the expecteds you're generating are all zero. Their contribution to chi-square is a sum of terms like $(0 - 0)^2/0$... but they're meaningless *anyway*, so it's actually a good thing the analysis doesn't work; better no answer than a meaningless one that appears meaningful - that's *dangerous*. Whoever has asked you to do such a thing apparently has no idea what they're doing.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks for your input. I have emailed my partner who's doing this assignment with me, regarding the flaw in the data. Could you recommend some other distribution that would produce a meaningful result? I'll talk to my professor about it.

Comment: What you need is some kind of model. A few numbers don't give nearly enough basis to come up with one. What is going on? What's the underlying question of interest?

Comment: Hi, are you still looking for an answer? I hope mine helped. If it did, don't forget to vote it up. You can also check your favorite answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 14):

As Glen_B pointed out, your problem is that you can't have expected frequencies to be zero, because that would throw off the calculation of the chi-squared statistic (you'd have zeros in the denominator). For example, see that

```
x1 <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 1), 2, 2)
x1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1
```

and

```
x2 <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1), 2, 2)
x2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
```

will both fail to produce chi-squared tests (as they should), whereas

```
x3 <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 1), 2, 2)
x3
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0
```

will give you no problems.

BTW, this issue was also addressed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10053/nan-p-value-when-using-rs-goodfit-on-binomial-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679660/r-chisq-test-with-p-values-na).